# Connect last row to another row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row

Every time a customer buys something, it appears on the "purchases" table and gets a new "id".

I now want to make a mySQL query that I can run on PHP and to do this:

1. Pick the last row on the "purchases" table and therefore recognize the customer of that last purchase.
2. Connect then to the "customers" table and show me the count of purchases of that customer.

I use this code but it shows me the quantity of purchases for every customer, not only the last one as I want.

```html
$mysqli = NEW MySQLI ('servername', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

$resultSet = $mysqli->query ("SELECT quantity FROM customers INNER JOIN purchases ON customers.customer=purchases.customer");

if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){

while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
 {   $count = $rows['quantity'];
 echo "<p>Number of purchases: $count";
 }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT quantity FROM customers 
WHERE customer= (select distinct customer 
                from purchases where 
                 id = (select max(b.id) from purchases as b))
```